# Get ImageButton background color

Tags: java, android, android-layout, background-color, imagebutton

if you take a look at this link as an excample http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/

My question is How can I get the ImageButton Background Color when the user clicked on that ImageButton?

Thanks.

Instead of showing a message...

```
       Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I would like to get the color value, so I can use it to change another control background color. Think of it as a Color Picker Dialogbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the color.

The background of a button is a Drawable:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
Drawable buttonBackground = button.getBackground();
```

if you know that the background is a color, you should try:

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
```

Comment: I've seen this post before and I've tried it. It crashed the app when it tried to cast the object to Button, BUT, I've just realized what I did wrong :-)

I should have cast it to ImageButton

So this is what I did and it Worked!!! Thank you all. I love StackExchange aka StackOverflow. You guys and gals rock!!!

ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resID);
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) imageButton.getBackground();

Comment: One more question. This getColor() method is not available in API 10 which I am targeting. So is there a different way of doing this for API 10?

Comment: No, it is not possible =( 
getColor() was introduced in Android 3.0
please mark the question as correct =)